# Real Analysis: Function Expansion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

"Expand the function

$$f(x) = e^x$$

in powers of $x + 1$ to the term containing $(x + 1)^3$"

The wording of this problem throws me off a bit, but I believe this involves Taylor Series Expansion. However, I am not exactly sure how to express it. What do you guys suggest? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Taylor around $x=-1$?

Comment: Suggestion.  Look just before this in the book, and see if there are some expansions in powers of something other than $x$.

Answer (score 4):

$f (x)=e^{x+1}e^{-1} $. For  the first  factor use the $e $- series